# How do I test private class methods with Jest?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, class, jestjs, private-methods

I have a class with private methods:

```
class MyClass {
  #myMethod () {}
}
```

Is it possible to test it with Jest?

Comment: You don't. Don't test private methods, they're implementation details. Test _behaviour_, through the public API.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Does this mean that you would not unit test a private method?

Comment: @nico not exactly, it means I wouldn't _directly call_ a private method from tests. Those methods still get tested via their use through the public interface.